# redux-form how to submit all registered fields

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have spent several hours trying to figure out how to do this, so I'm hoping you all can help. Here is my situation:

1. I have a complex, multi-page wizard wrapped in a redux-form
2. Essentially all inputs are optional. The user can go as far as they would like and can abandon the workflow early.
3. I want to start every field as null and only set the value of a field if the user has actually seen it. For example, I want to start a checkbox field value as null and only set it to false in the back-end if the user actually clicked through that wizard page, **even if they never interacted with the field.**
4. I want to avoid naming the fields on a wizard page or saving any wizard meta-data (e.g. the user has made it to page 4) at all costs. This would really reduce flexibility as our workflow is evolving rapidly and I would love for this to just work as I potentially move fields between pages.

Redux-form has been awesome for this general wizard use-case because it dynamically registers fields as they are rendered into the page. I can capture the values on next/submit and save them to the db, but it's only the subset that the user touched.

Ideally I'd be able to set some options to just submit the value of all registered fields, but that doesn't exist. The next option that I wanted to pursue is on mount of the page grab all registered fields and call onChange with the default value for that field so they all end up in form values. However, I cannot find any way to get a handle to the registered fields from redux-form. I suppose I could simply reach into the store to where I know they exist in the form state tree, but that seems very brittle and sloppy.

If I give the form initialValues, then everything submits. However, that doesn't really solve my problem because I still can't tell when the user has actually made a decision to keep a value as the default (i.e. has seen the page). Redux-form is already doing a good job of dynamically figuring out what form fields are on the page at a given time, I'd just like to leverage that.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Please let me know if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is probably here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2368#issuecomment-351690980

Basically, this suggests what I mentioned wanting to avoid in my question - reaching into the form state to get the registered fields. I think if I combine using initialValues for the entire form with filtering down to registered fields on submit via the code in the linked GitHub comment, I'll be able to make this work. Messy and not exactly ideal, but also not terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Redux Form's notion of registered fields will help you much here. Registered fields keeps track of which fields are mounted at any given point in time, not which fields that *have been mounted* at any point throughout the lifetime of the form.

You can put each page in a form section, and add some mechanism that at mount time flags that the form section has been mounted and (presumably) seen by the user. Then you can filter the whole form section at submit time without any knowledge about the contents, which is what you want to avoid.